# CHCSV Error : unable to allocate memory for length

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, csv

I want to parse a .csv file. For this I use the CHCSV Parser. But when I push into the view where the parser should start parsing, the app crashes.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSMallocException', reason:
>   '*** -[NSConcreteMutableData appendBytes:length:]: unable to allocate
>   memory for length (4294967295)'

```
NSString *filePath = @"http://somewhere.com/test.csv";
NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
self.csvParser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVFile:fileContent];
```

**Edit:**
I'm developing for iOS 6+. Thanks for the great comments and answers. I hope to get the right solution. 
*Input Stream*
It doesn't work. When I want to work with the input stream the app crashes because of the wrong encoding.

> > Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to 
> >     parameter of type 'NSStringEncoding *' (aka 'unsigned int *')

```
NSData *downloadData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/test.csv"]];
NSInputStream *stream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:downloadData];
self.csvParser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithInputStream:stream usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding delimiter:@";"];

self.csvParser.delegate = self;
[self.csvParser parse];
```

*CSV-String*

```
NSString *filePath = @"http://example.com/test.csv";
NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];  
self.csvParser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithCSVString:fileContent];

self.csvParser.delegate = self;
[self.csvParser parse];
```

This parse only `(null)`.

Comment: This code looks absolutely right to me. The error must be somewhere else. How large is test.csv?

Comment: just 2KB. I checked it with big and very small .csv files...

Comment: That's weird... I just tried the sample project and it works perfectly for both small and large files

Comment: You're developing for iOS 6+, right?

Comment: In my sample projet it doesn't work, too.

Comment: Yep. For iOS 6+. Why?

Comment: I just had a guess .. Now I am able to reproduce your issue .. I'll look for a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Final Edit:** Dave, the author of `CHCSVParser`, updated his code on github, so this problem should be solved when you use the most recent version. [Get it now!](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser)

---

Okay, here we go:

First add the following code in `CHCSVParser.m`:

In method `- (void)_sniffEncoding` at the very beginning you have:

```
uint8_t bytes[CHUNK_SIZE];
NSUInteger readLength = [_stream read:bytes maxLength:CHUNK_SIZE];
[_stringBuffer appendBytes:bytes length:readLength];
[self setTotalBytesRead:[self totalBytesRead] + readLength];
```

change it to:

```
uint8_t bytes[CHUNK_SIZE];
NSUInteger readLength = [_stream read:bytes maxLength:CHUNK_SIZE];
if (readLength > CHUNK_SIZE) {
    readLength = CHUNK_SIZE;
}
[_stringBuffer appendBytes:bytes length:readLength];
[self setTotalBytesRead:[self totalBytesRead] + readLength];
```

After that changed I got only `null` values so I changed the `file` path (in the sample project it is located in the `main()`, however I did the parsing in `viewDidLoad`.

*Make sure you copied the file in your bundle directory for that to work!*

```
file = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"scsv" inDirectory:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
```

**Edit:**

When you say you need to download the file you can do following (but notice that this is quick and dirty solution especially on mobile devices)

```
NSData *downloadData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourdomain.tld/Test.scsv"]];
NSInputStream *stream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:downloadData];
```

The last line is the important one here you need to change.

Hope that solves your issue.

**Edit 2:**

I've just created a repository with a demo project for you where the code actually works. Perhaps you can find out what you do wrong (or at least different). [Here is the link.](https://bitbucket.org/dennis_weissmann/chcsvparserdemo/src)

**Edit 3:**

Change

```
self.csvParser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithInputStream:stream usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding delimiter:@";"];
```

to

```
self.csvParser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithInputStream:stream usedEncoding:&encoding delimiter:';'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. The file has to be on a server. So the solution with the bundle doesn't fit really. 
Why am I the only person who has issues with it?

Comment: But that shouldn't matter - The important part is the one were you insert the if-condition

Comment: (CHCSVParser author here) Interesting, I guess I should change `readLength` to be signed, and check to make sure it's not negative.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dave you're welcome! Would be great when you made an answer (or tell me to edit mine) after editing so that we have a solved problem here ;)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing your sample project! This and the encoding issue solved it!

Comment: I've updated the CHCSVParser code to address this: https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser  Thanks for finding it!

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind I'll put that as (another) edit at the top of my post :)

Comment: Thank you for the great answers and for updating your code ;)